# Problem Handling error over loop array request

Tags: javascript, error-handling, request, cheerio

I've build a data **scraper** with cheerio to get some data from an array of url. It return me the exact same array of url more the data I've **scraped**. My output array is formatted like this :

```
[{url: urls, value: share}]
```

It's working perfectly but doesn't handle error :

```
function getNbShares(urls) {
    return Promise.map(urls, request).map((htmlOnePage, index) => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(htmlOnePage),
            share = $('.nb-shares').html();
        return {
            url: urls[index],
            value: share
        };
    });
}
```

so I tried doing this but doesn't work :

```
function getNbShares(urls) {
    return Promise.map(urls, request).map((htmlOnePage, index) => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(htmlOnePage);
            if(error) {
              return  {
                    url: urls[index],
                    value: null }
            } else {
            share = $('.nb-shares').html();
              if (!share) {
                   return  {
                    url: urls[index],
                    value: null }
                  } else {
                      return {
                          url: urls[index],
                           value: share
                      };
                  }}
    });
}
```

the idea is that whatever happen, it always return me the url, plus value as null if the url doesn't answer or if the **scraper** doesn't work.

I guess I need to pass a function like this `function(req,error)` but I don't where exactly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to "catch" the error? [Promise Catch Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch)

```
function getNbShares(urls) {
  return Promise.map(urls, request).map((htmlOnePage, index) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(htmlOnePage),
        share = $('.nb-shares').html();
    return {
        url: urls[index],
        value: share
    };
  })
    .catch((error) => {
        //do something here with error
    })
}
```

Comment: I tried something like this `.catch(function (err) { return urls.splice( urls[index], 1 ); getNbShares(urls);});` but doesn't work. The idea is that I don't only need to catch the error but also to build my array at the same time.

Comment: How about Promise.reduce instead of .map - that way if there is an "error" or value you don't want to put in the array, you don't have to.

Comment: Actually I want to put everything in my array as an object. I just don't want that getNbShares(urls) stop if an error is catch. Does my question is clear or should I rewrite it ?

Comment: @SimonBreton - Can you rewrite it? Also include a sample output of what you would like.